# Extracting specific part of column values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to extract a specific part of column values.
The target column and its values look like

```
TEMP_COL
---------------
DESCOL 10MG
TEGRAL 200MG 50S
COLOSPAS 135MG 30S
```

The resultant column should look like

```
RESULT_COL
---------------
10MG
200MG
135MG
```

Comment: You need to be clearer about the requirements. What are the rules / algorithm? For example, it could be 1. Every 2nd work; 2. The first word starting with a number; 3. Any work with MG as the suffix... etc

Comment: i didn't think of the algorithm at the time of asking the question. but i believe the required data can be extracted by reversing the column values then find `like 'MG%'` until the space occurs. although I couldn't figure out how to put the algorithm in actual SQL format.

Comment: Is it always a number followed by `MG` that you want to extract?

Comment: yes. its always a number ending at `MG`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using a regular expression:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(TEMP_COL, '[0-9]+MG')
FROM the_table;
```

Note that this is case sensitive and it always returns the *first* match.

Comment: This also assumes that the middle term uses milligrams as the unit of measure, which may not always be true.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably approach this using `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` rather than base functions, because the structure of the prescription text varies from record to record.

```
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEMP_COL, '(\s)(\S*)', 1, 1))
FROM yourTable
```

The pattern `(\s)(\S*)` will match a single space followed by any number of non-space characters.  This should match the second term in all cases.  We use `TRIM()` to remove a leading space which is matched and returned.

Answer (score 0):

how do you know what is the part you want to extract? how do you know where it begins and where it ends? using the white-spaces?

if so, you can use substr for cutting the data and instr for finding the white-spaces.

example:

```
select substr(tempcol, -- string
              instr(tempcol, ' ', 1), -- location of first white-space 
              instr(tempcol, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(tempcol, ' ', 1))  -- length until next space
from dual
```

another solution is using `regexp_substr` (but it might be harder on performance if you have a lot of rows):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (tempcol, '(\S*)(\s*)', 1, 2)
FROM dual;
```

edit: fixed the regular expression to include expressions that don't have space after the parsed text. sorry about that.. ;)

Comment: Your `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` has a problem.  Do you see what it is?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yup. fixed.